# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence with Decision Tree where all the rows have equal elements?

Tags: numpy, matrix, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to fit a decision tree to matrices of features and labels. Here is my code:

```
print FEATURES_DATA[0]
print ""
print TARGET[0]
print ""
print np.unique(list(map(len, FEATURES_DATA[0])))
```

which gives the following output:

```
[ array([[3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       ..., 
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6]], dtype=uint8)]

[ array([[31],
       [31],
       [31],
       ..., 
       [22],
       [22],
       [22]], dtype=uint8)]

[463511]
```

The matrix actually contains 463511 samples.

Thereafter, I run the following block:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
for i in xrange(5):
    Xtrain=FEATURES_DATA[i]
    Ytrain=TARGET[i]
    clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3d8b2a7a3e5f> in <module>()
      4     Ytrain=TARGET[i]
      5     clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
----> 6     clf.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)

C:\Users\singhg2\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    152         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    153         if check_input:
--> 154             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    155             if issparse(X):
    156                 X.sort_indices()

C:\Users\singhg2\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.pyc in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    371                                       force_all_finite)
    372     else:
--> 373         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    374 
    375         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I searched other posts on SO and found that most of the answers were that the matrices were not completely numbers, or the array is differing in the length across samples. But, this is not the case with my problem?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `print FEATURES_DATA[0]`
actually prints

```
[ array([[3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
       ..., 
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6]], dtype=uint8)]
```

then the problem is that FEATURES_DATA[0] is a python list with a numpy array inside it. (You can understand that from the `[` and `]`)

You can select the first (and only) element of of the list to fix it

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
for i in xrange(5):
    Xtrain=FEATURES_DATA[i][0]
    Ytrain=TARGET[i][0]
    clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
```

Comment: That indeed solves the problem. But how about growing the size of the training set? e.g. something on this line : Xtrain=Xtrain.append(FEATURES_DATA[i][0])

Comment: If you simply want to double the size Xtrain filling it with duplicates you can do `Xtrain = numpy.concatenate((Xtrain,Xtrain))`

Comment: Not doubling the Size, rather I wish Xtrain to grow with every iteration. So for first iteration, it should be FEATURES_DATA[i][0], but for second iteration it should be FEATURES_DATA[i][0] and FEATURES_DATA[i][1] concatenated. I have tried concatenation, and it gave me an error  "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
"

Comment: according to your print output `FEATURES_DATA[0][1]` does not exist and should raise an exception. Can you provide the shape of FEATURES_DATA? Try `print np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA).shape`

Comment: I get the following output : (6L, 1L)

Comment: Before the loop add: `FEATURES_DATA = np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA)` and in the loop do `Xtrain = np.concatenate(FEATURES_DATA[:i][0])`

Comment: I use the following code, and I get this error  in the Xtrain line : IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0               ..........................................................                                                                                                                                                                                                             features = np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA)
labels = np.asarray(TARGET)

for i in xrange(5):
    Xtrain = np.concatenate(features[:i][0])
    Ytrain=np.concatenate(labels[:i][0])

Comment: This is becoming a new question, so if you want further help please create a new question and add a bit more detail about what exactly you are doing. Also try adding a piece of code that can reproduce the error you are experiencing.

Comment: I did realize that. Here is the new question :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596630/error-in-appending-matrices-in-python

Comment: Also if you think this question was sufficiently answered please accept it :D