# Error in appending matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a set of features and labels for 6 different weeks stored in variable `FEATURES_DATA` and `TARGET` respectively.

What I want to do is to train a decision tree on growing features and labels. So, training on first week of data and testing on second week, then, training on first two weeks and testing on third week and so on...

To give an idea about my dataset:

```
print np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA).shape
print np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA[0][0]).shape
print ""
print FEATURES_DATA[0]
```

outputs:

```
(6L, 1L)
(463511L, 40L)

[ array([[3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
         [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
         [3, 3, 3, ..., 7, 7, 7],
         ..., 
         [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
         [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6],
         [2, 2, 2, ..., 6, 6, 6]], dtype=uint8)]
```

Here is the main code:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

features = np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA)
labels = np.asarray(TARGET)
for i in xrange(5):
    Xtrain = np.concatenate(features[:i][0])
    print Xtrain.shape
    Ytrain = np.concatenate(labels[:i][0])
    Xtest = FEATURES_DATA[i+1][0]
    Ytest = TARGET[i+1][0]
    clf_DT = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini', splitter='best', max_depth=None, min_samples_split=5000)
    clf_DT.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
```

I get the following error on `Xtrain` concatenation line:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5d87466a6a03> in <module>()
      6 
      7 for i in xrange(5):
----> 8     Xtrain = np.concatenate(features[:i][0])
      9     print Xtrain.shape
     10     Ytrain = np.concatenate(labels[:i][0])

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: can you also add the output of `print np.asarray(FEATURES_DATA).shape`

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to my problem. Initializing an empty matrix will solve the problem.

```
Xtrain=np.empty(shape=[0, 40])
for i in xrange(5):
    Xtrain=np.concatenate((Xtrain,FEATURES_DATA[i][0]))
    print Xtrain.shape
```

which gives the output

```
(463511L, 40L)
(955280L, 40L)
(1502984L, 40L)
(1969719L, 40L)
(2569141L, 40L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first iteration from line 7, i=0.

Your next statement extracts features[:0], which is empty: []

Thus, there is no element [0] to complete the expression features[:i][0] ... this is where you get the subscript error.

Perhaps try a range of 1, 5 ?

Comment: that's not the only problem. The data is a python list containing a numpy array, concatenating correctly is the question here. So, if I print size of Xtrain with xrange(1,5), I get the same dimensions